# How can I get cython to use a c++20 compiler?

Tags: cython

I am trying to use some features of std in C++20, but when I try to compile with Cython I get an error.

```
%%cython -a -+

from libcpp.bit cimport popcount
print(popcount(5))
```

> Content of stdout:
> _cython_magic_8a7cc06c3f4134f8362279784510a3a14b752950.cpp
> The contents of <bit> are available only with C++20 or later.

When I run a similar C++ program in visual studio it works just fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bit>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::popcount((unsigned int) 7);
}
```

> 3

How can I see what compiler I am using, or how can I set it to one which uses c++20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass an argument to the compiler to enable c++20, specifically `-std=c++20` for gcc or `/std:c++20` for msvc using the `--compile-args` or `-c` argument of [cython magic](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/config/extensions/cythonmagic.html).

```
%%cython -c=-std=c++20 --cplus

from libcpp.bit cimport popcount
print(popcount(<unsigned long>(5)))
```

this works on colab, which uses linux with gcc, for windows with msvc use `-c=/std:c++20` instead.

Comment: I tried both compile-args and they both give:  

%%cython -a -+ -c=/std=c++20  

cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/std=c++20'

%%cython -a -+ -c=-std=c++20  

cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++20'

Comment: ok... I found it. Thanks to your comment. I will accept yours if you make this correction:

`-c=/std:c++20` is the correct argument for MSVC. (Colon, not Equals)

Comment: @ToddSierens i fixed it, sorry for the mistake, i didn't have a pc with msvc and jupyter lying around.